# Difference between (ResourceWriter & ResXResourceWriter) and (ResourceReader & ResXResourceReader) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, resx

I wanted to create an XML File from Resouce File(.resx).

I succeeded in that by using `ResXResourceReader` class. But then I came to know that there exist another class for this purpose `ResourceReader`.

Then what is the difference between them? and which one should be used for this purpose.

Same case with ResourceWriter and ResXResourceWriter. What difference do they have between them?

Comment: Did you mean ResXResourceReader? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ResourceReader reads binary and ResXResourceReader reads XML.

[ResourceReader MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcereader.aspx)

> Enumerates the resources in a **binary resources (.resources)** file by
>   reading sequential resource name/value pairs.

[ResXResourceReader MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader.aspx)

> Enumerates **XML resource (.resx)** files and streams, and reads the
>   sequential resource name and value pairs.

More information can be found [here](http://flylib.com/books/en/3.147.1.114/1/).